# Skeptics.SE now an unofficial URL Shortener

Tags: discussion, support

There is no doubt that them term ***skeptics.se***, which stands shortly for Skeptics Stack Exchange (skeptics.stackexchange.com) is [very commonly used](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=skeptics.se) on this site, many times I have typed skeptics.se on my browser thinking it would link to skeptics.stackexchange.com and I got linked nowhere.

One time I wanted to share a question on skeptics on Twitter, and due to the characters limit I couldn't finish one single sentence (even with the stackexchange sharing link).
So, I had a search on a domain registrar and it seemed no one had registered the swedish domain name **skeptics.se**, I saw it as an opportunity and bought it. I have also had the idea to integrate it with the StackExchange API so that we could have a URL shortener for questions on this site.

So, currently:

> **skeptics.se**

redirects to

> **skeptics.stackexchange.com**

As for the questions, you just have to type skeptics.se along with the id of the question. For example:

> **skeptics.se/22345**

redirects to

> **skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22345/did-the-twitter-account-fifndhs-predict-the-exact-world-cup-results-ahead-of-tim**

I might create other redirects (for users and meta section) if this domain was pratical and effective.

Comment: +0 for using Godaddy.

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: What happened to this?  It seems to no longer work.  If you are not interested in maintaining it, I might be willing to take ownership of it.

Comment: @Ravenstine: fixed now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for that!

Please make sure you always use 302s.

Also, please don't use these on the site, but only to share our content elsewhere. We don't actually want a dependence on an external service in order to navigate the site.

Comment: StackExchange: Make this for all sites! This is cool!